# Query a nib file for frames, layout data

Tags: ios, nib

I have a UIView subclass that instantiates itself from a nib file.  Prior to that, I would like the superview to be able to ask the custom view what frame it's going to need/want.

Currently I have a class method on the custom view that I update by hand when the frame of the custom view in the nib is changed in IB.  Ideally I would like a class method that peeks in the nib and reports back directly from the nib.

How can I peek into a nib file and retrieve information from it?  Should I load it as NSData and parse the XML or is there something a little less brutal?

Answer (score 0):

If an instance method will work, you should be able to use the `-sizeThatFits:` method.

If it definitely needs to be a class method, you can write your own class method that is very similar to `-sizeThatFits:` where you take the `CGSize` param that is passed in and calculate the appropriate size for the view.

You're not specifically getting data from the nib, you're getting data from the associated class.

Comment: If I understand you, then in my original question I want to go the other way; I don't want to pass a size to the subview, I want the subview to report it's size up to the superview before being loaded.

Comment: You can pass in `CGSizeMax` as the size parameter and it will be like there's no size restraint at all.